# find this integral with complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

$$\int \frac{(z^{-3})e^{1/z}}1dz$$

I use tailor series but I cant solve it also I use common solution but I cant solve it

Comment: Is the integral over some path, or do you just want an antiderivative? And why is there a $1$ in the denominator?

Comment: I just want its antiderivative, I cant write this function correctly because dz goes into denominator !!

Comment: @NimaGorjinezhad You asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2332284). It seems you're having trouble using MathJax. Please go through [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You mean $\int \frac{\exp(\frac{1}{z})}{z^3 dz}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$\int z^{-3}e^{1/z}dz=- \int u(z)v'(z) dz$, where $u(z)=1/z$ and $v(z)=e^{1/z}$.

Your turn !

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is

$$ \int z^{-3}\, e^{1/z} dz=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}} (z-1)}{z}. $$